Writing list as disjoint union of input lists
Suppose I have two lists,
s1={{1,2,3},{3,1,2},{3,1,2},{2,3,1},{3,2,1},{1,3,2}}

and
s2={{1,2}->{{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{3,1,2}},{2,3}->{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{2,3,1}},
{1,3}->{{1,2,3},{2,1,3},{1,3,2}},{2,1}->{{2,1,3},{2,3,1},{3,2,1}},
{3,2}->{{1,3,2},{3,1,2},{3,2,1}},{3,1}->{{3,2,1},{2,3,1},{3,1,2}}}

These associations relate sublists of s1 to new sets. What I would want is a function that realises that s1 can be written as the disjoint union of the following two sets values in s2
s1==ResourceFunction["MultisetIntersection"][s1,Join[{{1,2,3},{1,3,2},{3,1,2}},{{3,2,1},{2,3,1},{3,1,2}}]]

and outputs the corresponding keys:
{{1,2},{3,1}}

This function should work for sets that can be written as disjoint unions of more than two set values in s2. If multiple are available, a specific one should be chosen. I'm asking for suggestions because the simplest ways I can think of to achieve this are too computationally expensive (the code should be relatively fast for s2 containing upwards of 30 associations)

''the simplest ways I can think of are too computationally expensive" - can you include your attempts or at least the algorithms you thought up?

In this specific case, I would generate all subsets of s2 with two elements. Then, for each of these subsets, check if the union of the lists contained within them gives s1. This however is very unpractical for larger sets due to the exploding number of subsets.
